# Check reference when delete entity value was not reference to other entities

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

i have to delete one records of country table and before that i need to check
whether that Id is reference to other tables. if that ID does not exists in any reference table then and then i will delete that record.

How can i check this situation through Entity framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to consider any of **Code first**, **Database first** or **Model first** with **.edmx** approaches to build your data access layer.

By default, the database will prevent you from deleting a row in `country` table if there are related rows in one of the other tables.

If you update the database with the [cascade delete rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738695(v=vs.100).aspx#sectionSection4) and then update the existing model from the database, the Entity Framework will add the cascade delete rule to the [SSDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716745(v=vs.100).aspx) but not [CSDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716734(v=vs.100).aspx). You will have to add it manually. For e.g., to delete a row from `Person`, see the image below

[image][image]
In Server Explorer, open the database diagram. Right-click the relationship between Person and StudentGrade (the line between tables), and then select Properties.

To specify the cascade delete rule in the conceptual model, select the association on the Entity Designer surface. Then, in the Properties window, select Cascade for the OnDelete property.

[image][image]

Ref: [Configuring Database Rules to Allow Deletion](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-2)

Ref: [Cascade Delete Rules on Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738695(v=vs.100).aspx#sectionSection4)

Also, for **Code First** approach, in your database context, you can specify a rule to cascade on delete as below.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasMany(e => e.PersonCountry).WithOptional(s => s.Country).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    //...
}
```

Ref: [Delete cascade with code first (Poco)](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/entity-framework-4-3-delete-cascade-with-code-first-poco)

Ref: [Enabling Cascade Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete)